# Where to place "among other things"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

I'll be placing a short introduction on a web site and the introduction includes a sentence similar to this:

> I'm – among many other things – a hobbyist coder.

I'm unsure about the position of "among many other things". Other scenarios I can think of

> Among many other things, I'm a hobbyist coder.
>
> I'm a hobbyist coder, among many other things.

Which one should I be using? Or is there a better way to put it?

---

<sub>"Many" in "among many other things" is optional.</sub>

Comment: All three are fine, really, except that leaving that little, contracted _I’m_ all on its lonesome there at the beginning is quite clumsy (contracted forms cannot stand alone as full sentences, and parts of sentences that are cut off by pauses and parenthetical statements are, to a certain degree, similar)—I would uncontract it to _I am—among other things—a hobbyist coder_.

Comment: @Janus I was about to demand that you uncoin 'uncontract' until I realised I'd have used it too.

Comment: wouldn't the use of the word "hobbyist" already convey that it's not your primary function in life?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for writing advice

Answer (score 2):

Personally, although I'm not ure it's wrong, I wouldn't break up your sentence with the phrase on a website, so I'd use either of your other alternatives. But if your website is going to have sections dealing with at least some of the other things, I would probably leave it out entirely.